# System of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How can I solve this system of trigonometric equations for $0 \leq a\leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq b\leq2\pi$

$$\cos a + \cos (a+b) = 0$$

$$\cos b + \cos (a+b) = 0$$

the plot shows three points of intersection:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%7BCos%5Bx%5D+%2B+Cos%5Bx+%2B+y%5D+%3D%3D+0%2C+Cos%5By%5D+%2B+Cos%5Bx+%2B+y%5D+%3D%3D+0%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C2+pi%7D%2C+%7By%2C+0+%2C+2pi%7D%5D

Comment: Assuming you don't have a typo.. try subtracting the two equations.

Comment: Let $a=b$ and simplify it to one equation to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(A+B)=-\cos A=\cos(\pi-A)\implies A+B=2m\pi\pm(\pi-A)$$  where $m$ is any integer

Taking the - sign, $B=(2m-1)\pi$

$$0=\cos B+\cos(A+B)=\cos((2m-1)\pi)+\cos(A(2m-1)\pi)$$
$$\iff\cos A=1\implies A=2r\pi$$

Consider the + sign similarly.

$$B=(2m+1)\pi-2A$$

$$0=\cos B+\cos(A+B)=\cos\{(2m+1)\pi-2A\}+\cos\{A+(2m+1)\pi-2A\}$$
$$\implies-\cos2A-\cos A=0$$

$$\implies2\cos^2A+\cos A-1=0$$

Comment: shouldn't you get $\cos a = \cos b$, not $\cos a = \cos(a+b)$, or are you leaving out some steps there?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, Thanks for your observations